# How can I check component/page is published to which target?

Tags: 2011, 2013-sp1, core-service

I have a situation where I have to find out those publication targets which are deleted some time back in order to unpublish those components/pages which are published and now they are not being unpublished and further not able to delete. (In this case publication targets are not known) I am using coreservice 2011/2013.

Comment: Uhm as far as I know it's not possible to delete Publication Targets while there are items published to them. So exactly how did you delete them?

Answer (score 1):

Well, As Peter K mentions in the comments it would be interesting to know how did you delete the Publication Targets.

But to fix your issue you can try:

1. Get the Tcm Ids of the deleted Publication Targets (If somehow you can find those or you have it already)
2. And then use Core Service to un-publish the items.

You can you below example function for it:

```
public void UnPublishComponent(string[] componentId, string[] targets, bool includeChildren)
        {
            UnPublishInstructionData pub = new UnPublishInstructionData();
            pub.ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData() { IncludeChildPublications = includeChildren, IncludeComponentLinks = false };

            PublishTransactionData[] pubTranData = tridionClient.UnPublish(componentId, pub, targets, PublishPriority.High, null);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks **Saurabh**. This I have already tried, but need to code, if I don't know the publication Targets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply **Peter**, Actually I have got this situation, don't know how the other team in my company which were earlier doing this task has deleted the publication targets.

Comment: Possibly DB hacking or they may have used some of the (many) "flaws" in the old COM API.